# Check is SFTP directory exists before trying to create it using phpseclib

Tags: php, codeigniter, sftp, phpseclib

I have the following function in my model:

```
public function createfolder($location, $name){
    define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', NET_SFTP_LOG_COMPLEX);
    $sftp = new Net_SFTP('xx.xxx.xx.xx');
    if (!$sftp->login('admin', '********')) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }
    //moves to a location (Job folder for example)
    $sftp->chdir($location);
    //makes the folder
    $sftp->mkdir($name);
}
```

This will work but I would like to add some sort of error prevention validation, how can I check if a folder exists using SFTP?

---

Think I came up with a solution:

> `chdir()` changes directories, `mkdir()` creates directories, and `rmdir()` removes directories. In the event of failure, they all return `false`. `chdir()`, `mkdir()`, and `rmdir()` return `true` on successful completion of the operation.

So I can use an `if` statement to check `if chdir() === true` or `false` to see if the directory is there.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `$sftp->is_dir($location)` to check if it's a directory.

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is a good one.

In theory you could also do something like `$sftp->stat('filename')['permissions'] & 0170000 == 0040000` I think. That's a hack borrowed from phpseclib itself:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/7a2c7a414c08d28f0700c7f6f8686a9e0e246a44/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php#L1969